# Session did't store values in live site

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-4, session-variables, session-cookies

I am using laravel 4.2 and in my live site session did't store values. This way Auth::attemp(); working fine but Auth::check(); return always false. I already try to change domain name in session file. Thanks in advance

routes.php

```
Route::controller('/admin', 'adminIndex');
```

adminIndex.php

```
function getShow()
{
   if (Auth::check())
    {
        return View::make('dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('admin');
    }
}

function postIndex()
{
    $username = Input::get('username');
    $password = Input::get('password');

    if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password), true))
    {
        return Redirect::to("admin/show/");
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('admin')->with('message', 'Invalid User Name / Password.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Now check. I am update my Question.

Comment: Is your controller name `adminIndex` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auth function not working properly. it's approve your credential and destroy session. Update your laravel library and try.